# Tensorflow: gradients suddenly became NaNs during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradient

I am training simple variational autoencoder with negative binomial likelihood for decoder. I used python 3.7.1 and tensorflow 2.0.0.

The model was trained well without any problems for tens of epochs, but all weights, loss, and gradients suddenly became NaN during training. I modified the code to find which variables become NaN first (among weights, loss, and gradients) and found that gradients first became nan and this affected other variables.

I have googled similar issues but most of case nan appeared in the loss, which is different from this case. I tried: smaller learning rate, clipping loss... but nothing could resolve the problem.

Here is the model class for autoencoder model:

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, latent_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder_fc_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_dim, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        self.encoder_fc_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_dim, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        self.encoder_latent = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim)

    def call(self, input):
        h = tf.math.l2_normalize(input, 1)
        h = self.encoder_fc_1(h)
        h = self.encoder_fc_2(h)
        return tf.split(self.encoder_latent(h), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)

class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, vocab_size):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.decoder_fc_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_dim, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        self.decoder_fc_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_dim, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
        self.decoder_fc_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size + vocab_size)
    
    def call(self, z):
        h = self.decoder_fc_1(z)
        h = self.decoder_fc_2(h)
        return tf.split(self.decoder_fc_3(h), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)

class NBVAE(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(NBVAE, self).__init__()
        self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(config["learning_rate"])
        self.encoder = Encoder(config["hidden_dim"], config["latent_dim"])
        self.decoder = Decoder(config["hidden_dim"], config["vocab_size"])

    def call(self, input):
        mean, logvar = self.encoder(input)
        z = reparameterize(mean, logvar)
        h_r, h_p = self.decoder(z)
        return mean, logvar, z, h_r, h_p

def reparameterize(mean, logvar):
    eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
    return tf.add(tf.multiply(eps, tf.math.exp( tf.math.divide(logvar, 2))), mean)

def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
    log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
    return tf.reduce_sum(-.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi), axis=raxis)

def compute_logpx_z(input, h_r, h_p):
    temp = tf.exp(-tf.multiply(tf.exp(h_r), tf.math.log(tf.exp(h_p) + 1)))
    temp_cliped = tf.clip_by_value(temp, 1e-5, 1 - 1e-5)
    ll = tf.multiply(input, tf.math.log(1 - temp_cliped)) + tf.multiply(1 - input, tf.math.log(temp_cliped))
    #print("logpx_z: {}".format(tf.reduce_sum(ll, axis=-1)))
    return tf.reduce_sum(ll, axis=-1), temp

def compute_loss(model, input):
    mean, logvar, z, h_r, h_p = model(input)
    logpx_z, temp = compute_logpx_z(input, h_r, h_p)
    logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
    logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
    return tf.negative(tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x)), temp
```

and here is the code snippet for training the model.
I put some if statements in the middle of the code to check which variable become NaN first.

```
    print("start training...")
    num_batches = int(np.ceil(len(training_data) / batch_size))
    epoch_loss = []

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("epoch: {}".format(epoch+1))
        progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(num_batches)
        loss_record = []
    
        for i in range(num_batches):
            x_batch = training_data[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            x_batch = one_hot(x_batch, depth=len(concept2id))

            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                loss, temp = compute_loss(nbvae, x_batch)
            print("step{s} loss: {l}".format(s=i, l=loss.numpy()))

            # checking the loss
            if np.isnan(loss.numpy()):
                print("nan loss is detected")
                detect_nan = True
                break

            loss_record.append(loss.numpy())
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, nbvae.trainable_variables)
            #gradients, global_norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tape.gradient(loss, nbvae.trainable_variables), 10)

            print("checking gradients...")
            gradient_nancount = 0
            for _, grad in enumerate(gradients):
                gradient_nancount += np.sum(np.isnan(grad))
            if gradient_nancount != 0:
                print("nan is detected in gradients")
                print("saving the current gradients and weights...")
                save_data(os.path.join(output_path, "error_gradients.pkl"), gradients)
                save_data(os.path.join(output_path, "error_tvariables.pkl"), nbvae.trainable_variables)
                detect_nan = True
                break

            nbvae.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, nbvae.trainable_variables))
            
            print("checking the updated weights...")
            weight_nancount = 0
            for _, weight in enumerate(nbvae.weights):
                weight_nancount += np.sum(np.isnan(weight))
            if weight_nancount != 0:
                print("nan is detected in weights")
                print("saving the current gradients and weights...")
                save_data(os.path.join(output_path, "error_gradients.pkl"), gradients)
                save_data(os.path.join(output_path, "error_tvariables.pkl"), nbvae.trainable_variables)
                detect_nan = True
                break
            progbar.add(1)
        
        if detect_nan:
            epoch_loss.append(np.nan)
            nbvae.save_weights(os.path.join(output_path, "nbvae_error{}".format(epoch+1)))
            break
        print("average epoch loss: {}".format(np.mean(loss_record)))
        epoch_loss.append(np.mean(loss_record))
```

Anyone knows the way to resolve this problem or possible reasons? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: You're likely suffering exploding gradients: https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/

Comment: @BtcSources Hi, thanks for your comment. That's possible, but I have already tried to avoid exploding gradient by clipping gradients, (see #gradients, global_norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tape.gradient(loss, nbvae.trainable_variables), 10) code line in the code snippet for training the model) but nan still appeared in gradients.

Comment: @JayLee try to clip parameters of `exp()` and `log()`

Comment: Hi @Andrey, thanks for your comment. Did you mean parameters in loss?

Comment: @JayLee No - I mean arguments of all `exp()`, `log()` calls.

Comment: This might be because of faulty input, make sure that you do not have bad input dataset. Thanks!